# Laravel date validation literal 'after' value

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form request file which validates my `start_date` form input.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'start_date' => 'required|date|after:2017-06-31',
    ];
}
```

I have placed a literal value in the after value, this however doesn't look like its working. Can someone advise the best way to do this?

**Edit:**
This is the dump from my `$request->all()`;

```
{
"_token": "tZa4e39ejrGHtrlpOYrUPfZ8PgSeD8FelY4voKni",
"start_date": "2017-07-01"
}
```

This is my form request validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'start_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after:2017-06-31',
    ];
}
```

I am using Laravel v5.4

Comment: Can  you clarify "doesn't look like its working"?

Comment: Dates before and after this date fail the validation

Comment: So ... all dates fail the validation? What value (and format) are you submitting?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `Y-m-d`

Comment: Can you give us the actual value you're submitting? And your Laravel version?

Comment: I'm using v5.4 and the request information has been pasted above

Answer (score 0):

> The dates will be passed into the PHP strtotime function so change
>   your date format to Y-m-d .

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'start_date' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:2017-06-31',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I have made your suggested changes, however all dates seem to fail now. FYI I can confirm looking at the post parameters, `Y-m-d` date format is being using.